# Putty SSH client command history?

Tags: command-line, bash, history

I connect to my server via Putty SSH client.

With the key <kbd>↑</kbd> I see previous entered commands, one by one. I just wondering is there a some command, which show all previous entered commands out of a simple list. Something like the command `ls` show the list directory contents.

---

I mark the list of all commands, but cant click with the second mouse button or Ctrl + C to copy all commands. Do you have idea how i can copy all commands list?

Answer (score 8):

To get a simple list of previously entered commands in the bash shell, you can use the command

```
history
```

The fact that you are using PuTTY or any other SSH client should be irrelevant.

Comment: If you have a non clean closure of Putty connection, history can be lost...why?

Comment: @Freedo probably the history only gets written to file when the shell exits cleanly - up to that point, it is volatile